# Finding specific tag using selenium in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webautomation

I am trying to reach youtube subscribe button using selenium and then click it.
[image]

I have tried everything, find_by_class, find_by_tagname, etc.
This is the syntax I am using:

```
subscribe_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('style-scope ytd-subscribe-button-renderer')
subscribe_button.click()
```

I tried using xpath, but I failed.
So how can I reach that button, once I am on Channel page of any channel on youtube?
and say if I want to reach a tag using its attributes, how can I do that?

Comment: please paste the DOM as text, not as screenshot.

Comment: this xpath may work: //*[contains(@class, 'ytd-subscribe-button-renderer')]//*[contains(@class,'ytd-subscribe-button-renderer') and text()='Subscribed']

Answer (score 0):

You can try below xpath:

```
//*[@id='subscribe-button' and @class='style-scope ytd-video-secondary-info-renderer']//*[text()='Subscribed']
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using **browser.find_element_by_xpath()**:

```
# Press subscribe button on youtube channel

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

URL = "https://www.youtube.com/c/MedlifeCrisis"

# Browser options
options = Options()
options.headless = True
firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", True)

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
browser.get(URL)

try:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="subscribe-button"]').click() # Click subscribe button
    print("Pressed subscribe button.")
except:
    print("Subscribe button not found")
```

The only tricky thing about it is the 'button' is actually a 'div'. This should work regardless of if the text is currently "Subscribe" or "Subscribed" since it uses @id.